# Is it possible to write custom cast operators in C++ (like `static_cast`)?

Tags: c++, casting

I get this idea and attempted to write a `string_cast` casting operator to cast between C++ strings.

```
template <class OutputCharType>
class string_cast
{
    public:
        template <class InputCharType>
        operator std::basic_string<OutputCharType>(const std::basic_string<InputCharType> & InputString)
        {
            std::basic_string<OutputCharType> OutputString;
            const std::basic_string<InputCharType>::size_type LENGTH = InputString.length();
            OutputString.resize(LENGTH);
            for (std::basic_string<OutputCharType>::size_type i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
            {
                OutputString[i] = static_cast<OutputCharType>(OutputString[i]);
            }
            return OutputString;
        }
};
```

I tried to use it like this:

```
std::string AString("Hello world!");
std::cout  << AString << std::endl;
std::wcout << string_cast<wchar_t>(AString) << std::endl; // ERROR
```

The error message is:

```
Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from
'const std::string' to 'string_cast<wchar_t>'
```

Is this impossible in C++, or am I missing something in my code?

Comment: You `string_cast` class has no constructor other than the default one. So it doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: It seems you just want function not class here.

Answer (score 9):

You may write free function with signature:

```
template <typename OutputCharType, typename InputCharType>
std::basic_string<OutputCharType>
string_cast(const std::basic_string<InputCharType>& InputString)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just want a non-member function rather than a functor:

```
template <class OutputCharType, class InputCharType>
std::basic_string<OutputCharType> 
string_cast(const std::basic_string<InputCharType> & InputString)
{
    std::basic_string<OutputCharType> OutputString;
    const auto LENGTH = InputString.length();
    OutputString.resize(LENGTH);
    for (auto i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
    {
        OutputString[i] = static_cast<OutputCharType>(OutputString[i]);
    }
    return OutputString;
}
```

Also note that I changed the `size_type` types to `auto`. That's because they are dependent names, so you'd need to use `typename` to use them as types (MSVC might let you get away without it, but this is not portable):

```
const std::basic_string<InputCharType>::size_type LENGTH = InputString.length();
//change to
const typename std::basic_string<InputCharType>::size_type LENGTH = InputString.length();    
//    ^^^^^^^^
```

This gets pretty ugly, so it's best to just use `auto`. If you can't use C++11, you could create `InSize` and `OutSize` `typedef`s.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that Jarod42's answer is a better way to go. The reason you get an error, is the fact that you attempt to use a conversion operator without an object.

`string_cast<wchar_t>(AString)`

is an attempt to invoke a c'tor that accepts a `std::string&`. Your code snippet requires the following syntax.

`string_cast<wchar_t>()(AString)`  Note the extra pair of `()`, which is object creation.